# android get actual time

Tags: android, time, timezone

I am designing an app. I am facing this one problem. I want to get time from the user's device even if the user has changed the time(which is not the exact correct time).

+

If the user changes the time or time-zone, somehow; the application should notify the app.

However, I need to check this offline. Please suggest me a suitable way to tackle this Candy crush-like scenario in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to understand what the problem is from your description. What do you mean "even if the user has changed the time". The system doesn't know who set the time. It just has a time, which is the time you get when you ask the system for the time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the UTC time. `System.currentTimeMillis()` [REF](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())